# Import CSV and plotting ECDF

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm having some troubles on how to use Empirical Cumulative Distribution function.

I have a CSV file containing 100k values (exported from excel), which I'm importing like so:

```
MyData <- read.csv(file="test.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

which seems to be okay but as soon when I type

```
P = ecdf(MyData)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

I've noticed `MyData[1]` outputs all my values and tried 
    `P = ecdf(MyData[1])` but alas I get the same error.

I've searched around and it seems the error pops up in a lot of scenarios so I can't really find what the exact issue is, any help will be nice as I'm extremely new to this.

Comment: Maybe you should do `ecdf(MyData[, 1])` or `ecdf(MyData[[1]])`

Comment: @JilberUrbina That works, thanks but what does the comma signify? Is it similar to a 2D Array?

Comment: read [help file for "["](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) for you to understand how to use comma inside `[`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use either `ecdf(MyData[, 1])` or `ecdf(MyData[[1]])` because `ecdf` expects a numeric vector as intput. When you use `MyData[1]` R will print all values but it is a dataframe, not a vector.

From `ecdf` help file you can read that `x`, the input for ecdf should be a numeric  vector.

Answer (score 1):

At least from my reading of `ecdf`, the input is a vector. So you'll need to pass a vector from your dataframe by specifying the column. You can do this by doing `P <- ecdf(MyData$col1)`, where col1 is the name of that factor, or by doing so numerically: `P <- ecdf(MyData[,1]`, which subsets the data, to all rows of column 1.